# Salesforce - Search display using two custom objects

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have created 2 custom objects - 'user details' and 'salary'. 
In user details I have this field `employee id`. If I am searching for some user by entering its `employee id`,I want to display the salary details of the user in the search table too.

As I am new to *salesforce.com*, can anyone please give me the code for this??

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 ways you could do this.

1. Create a formula in the user detail to bring the value of the salary from the salary object.

formula may look something like this.... (depending on your objects set up)

salary__r.Salary_Value__c

then in the search results, just include the Salary__c field in the user details object

**or**

1. create a visualforce page that will make a soql query and bring the values to be displayed on the page in a repeater.

The former is the easier option, the latter gives you more flexibility and customization.

Comment: I have created a lookup between user details and salary.

Comment: I want to use wrapper class for this. Can u please give me the code for this?? Thanks